# Set flag in new column based on the max(version) of the record

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table where it has multiple columns but need to be flagged as Y when the version is max compared to other record.
For example a simple table with two rows below . I want to add another column to flag Y when the version is highest for the user_id , week_id and start_time combination or set to N where version is not highest . The activity time or extract id should not be  included for the grouping.

| USER | WEEK_ID | START_TIME | ACTIVITY_TIME | EXTRACT_ID | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-12T00:00:00 | 2023-10-12T10:00:00 | A | 5 |
| USer 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-12T00:00:00 | 2023-10-12T09:00:00 | B | 2 |

Let me know how this can be achieved.

Need solution for flagging only max version records.

Output expected is

| USER | WEEK_ID | START_TIME | ACTIVITY_TIME | EXTRACT_ID | VERSION | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-12T00:00:00 | 2023-10-12T10:00:00 | A | 5 | Y |
| USer 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-12T00:00:00 | 2023-10-12T09:00:00 | B | 2 | N |

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issues are you facing? Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are perfect for this:

```sql
select *
  , iff(
      version = max(version) over(partition by user, week_id, start_time)
      , 'Y'
      , 'N'
  ) as flag
from table
```